# Ruby stack trace not showing defined method names

Tags: ruby, callback, callstack

I'm trying to create a way to put messages in the stack, so callbacks can look up their context by finding the nearest message in the stack.

My idea for how to do that was to dynamically create method names that are recognizable and have an ID embedded in the name, so a callback can look back up the stack and find the ID.

I've attempted to implement that using `define_singleton_method`, and it works to the extent that the defined method is invoked and runs the block it's given, but the `caller_locations` within that block do not contain the defined method name (even though it was clearly invoked).

**How can I get dynamically defined method names to appear in the `caller_locations`?**

Here is the draft implementation:

```
class StackMessage
    @@prefix="stack_message"
    @@next_key = 10000000
    @@values = {}
    def self.nest value, &block
        key = next_key
        stack_entry_label = "#{@@prefix}_#{key}".to_sym
        @@values[key] = value
        private
        puts "defining method #{stack_entry_label.inspect} with body #{block.inspect}"
        r = define_singleton_method stack_entry_label, Proc.new do
            yield block
        end
        puts "method definition returned #{r.inspect}"
        begin
            send stack_entry_label
        ensure
            eigenclass = class<<StackMessage; self; end
            eigenclass.send :remove_method, stack_entry_label
            @@values.delete key
        end
    end
    private
    def self.next_key
        r = @@next_key
        @@next_key = @@next_key.succ
        r
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    StackMessage.nest "test" do
        puts " ---------- IT'S ALIVE"
        puts caller_locations.inspect
        puts " ----------"
    end
end
```

and its output:

```
defining method :stack_message_10000000 with body #<Proc:0x00007fac62873c30@test.rb:32>
method definition returned :stack_message_10000000
 ---------- IT'S ALIVE
["test.rb:16:in `nest'", "test.rb:32:in `<main>'"]
 ----------
```

Comment: do you have a basic test suite re: the above on github etc?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon test suite?  I don't even have the fundamental operating mechanism worked out, what would I be testing for?  Is there a particular piece of information missing from the question?

Comment: the problem (for me) is that i don't understand your question, was hoping a simple test (via expectation) would help me understand it, if that was available

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify the bolded core question: **How can I get dynamically defined method names to appear in the `caller_locations`?**  I've dynamically defined a method, and invoked it by name, but within the block that the method yields the name of the dynamically defined method does not appear in the call stack returned by `caller_locations`

Comment: is this on the right track? https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/626f6685071b923c6c1a1d23a7c04e47

Comment: That looks like it's just listing all methods, not deriving them from the stack.  I suppose if nothing was ever concurrent it might be enough to take the one with the highest ID, but this has to work asynchronously so the highest ID won't always be the right one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't full understand/appreciate the actual problem that you are trying to solve: "I'm trying to create a way to put messages in the stack, so callbacks can look up their context by finding the nearest message in the stack"....Would you be able to demo this with a hello world code sample?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is that some callback functions don't get adequate information from their parameters.  In particular, I have some prepends on Net::HTTP to intercept network requests made by libraries we use in a Sidekiq worker that need to have some information about what we're asking the library to do that triggered this request.  If I could demo it I wouldn't be asking how to do it.

Comment: it's hard to conceptualize the problem without a very basic hello world of the *problem* (not the solution). if you could post that, it would be very helpful. cheers

Comment: for me it is a very interesting problem, i wish to have a crack at this, i've put in some time to solve it, but am handicapped by lack of understanding for this particular problem, and also unfamiliar with this domain

Comment: This is in a big project built on tools I haven't used to start anything from scratch, so making a hello world would have a steep learning curve; my cursory search for a sidekiq hello world didn't find one, if you can link to one I can try to build on that.  The problem may be equivalent to identifying which concurrent invocation of the same sidekiq worker is running.